# check if <p1> tag is not exist in <M> add this <p1><a>1223</a></p1> into it

Tags: php, xml

My XML something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <document>
  <consonant>
    <L>
      <l1>l1</l1>
    </L>
    <M>
      <m1>m1</m1>
    </M>
    <N>
      <n1>n1</n1>
    </N>
   </consonant>

  <consonant>
      <L>
        <l1>l1</l1>
      </L>
      <M>
         <m1>m1</m1>
      </M>
      <N>
        <n1>n1</n1>
      </N>
      </consonant>

</document>
```

check if `<p1> tag is not exist` in  `add this <p1><a>1223</a></p1>` into it.

```
   <consonant>
      <L>
        <l1>l1</l1>
      </L>
      <M>
      <m1>m1</m1>
      <p1><a>1223</a></p1>
      </M>
      <N>
        <n1>n1</n1>
      </N>
   </consonant>
```

I am trying :

```
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($myxml); // return object
   $nss = $xml->getDocNamespaces(TRUE);
   $xml->registerXPathNamespace('__empty_ns', $nss[""]);
   $result = $xml->xpath("/__empty_ns:Document/__empty_ns:consonant");//consonant node
   foreach($result as $key=>$value){ // loop through all <consonant>
          if(!array_key_exist('p1')){ // if not exist
                $value['p1'] = // add node here <p1><a>1223</a></p1>
          }
   }
```

and used the object operation on it (condifion ,loop,append,.)

anybody could tell me how Can I do this ?

Comment: So you tried to load the XML with SimpleXml and that's it? What else have you tried? Show your script. Does it work? If so, why dont you need another solution? Also, can you clarify what you are trying to do because `check if <p1> tag is not exist in <M> add this <p1><a>1223</a></p1> into it.` doesnt make much sense to me

Comment: Sounds like the correct approach to me. But we can't see what you're doing, and you provide no definition for "better". Perhaps a more in-depth question would be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: yes ,thank for both comments ,I upated the question.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document
    xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.02"
>
    <consonant>
        <L>
            <l1>l1</l1>
        </L>
        <M>
            <m1>m1</m1>
        </M>
        <N>
            <n1>n1</n1>
        </N>
    </consonant>

    <consonant>
        <L>
            <l1>l1</l1>
        </L>
        <M>
            <m1>m1</m1>
            <p1>unchanged</p1>
        </M>
        <N>
            <n1>n1</n1>
        </N>
    </consonant>
</document>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNameSpace('what-ever', 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.02'); // 'what-ever' can be anything other than an empty string

foreach ($xpath->query('//what-ever:consonant/what-ever:M[not(what-ever:p1)]') as $node) { // select M-nodes without p1-nodes as children
    $p1Node = $node->appendChild($dom->createElement('p1'));

    // do stuff with $p1Node
    $aNode = $p1Node->appendChild($dom->createElement('a', '1234'));
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <consonant>
        <L>
            <l1>l1</l1>
        </L>
        <M>
            <m1>m1</m1>
            <p1><a>1234</a></p1></M>
        <N>
            <n1>n1</n1>
        </N>
    </consonant>

    <consonant>
        <L>
            <l1>l1</l1>
        </L>
        <M>
            <m1>m1</m1>
            <p1>unchanged</p1>
        </M>
        <N>
            <n1>n1</n1>
        </N>
    </consonant>
</document>
```

Comment: yes,it works for<Document>.but If I change  to <Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:test.001.001.02"> it does not work.do you have any   idea?